# Android application using JSONObject doesn't work on a device using API 19

Tags: android, mysql, json

I'm trying to make an android application using a mysql database and php. The code works well on a device using API 21 but on a device using API 19, there is this error :

> Exception: Value Exception of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

I saw solutions for JSONArray but not for JSONObject.

This is MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText name, password;
String Name, Password;
Context ctx = this;
String NAME = null, PASSWORD = null, EMAIL = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_name);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_password);
}

public void main_register(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
}

public void main_login(View v) {
    Name = name.getText().toString();
    Password = password.getText().toString();
    BackGround b = new BackGround();
    b.execute(Name, Password);
}

class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String name = params[0];
        String password = params[1];
        String data = "";
        int tmp;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://something.com/login.php");
            String urlParams = "name=" + name + "&password=" + password;

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            while ((tmp = is.read()) != -1) {
                data += (char) tmp;
            }

            is.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return data;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        String err = null;
        try {

            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONObject user_data = root.getJSONObject("user_data");

            NAME = user_data.getString("name");
            PASSWORD = user_data.getString("password");
            EMAIL = user_data.getString("email");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Home.class);
        i.putExtra("name", NAME);
        i.putExtra("password", PASSWORD);
        i.putExtra("email", EMAIL);
        i.putExtra("err", err);
        startActivity(i);

     }
  }
}
```

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Look at the value of `s` in `onPostExecute()`. Presumably, it is not JSON. Perhaps it will give you some clues as to why your HTTP request is not working. You might also consider using more modern techniques for making asynchronous Web service requests (e.g., Retrofit).

Comment: The easiest way to check is to compare the contents of the `String`  in API 21 and API 19. What is the difference?

Comment: @CommonsWare : I've followed your suggestion and I've finally resolved the problem by using retrofit.